# how to refresh updatePanel with asp.net Timer control only once?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="100" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                   // my code is here
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePane>
```

above code refresh update panel in the period time.

Comment: Why would you use a timer for updating?  Updating should be a function of the data changing.

Comment: Maybe this can help you :  http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewfrederick/controlling-the-asp-net-timer-control-with-javascript. Run once and then disable/stop the timer.